# MouseClick on Label

Tags: events, swt, mouse, listener

I am trying to register a click on a label, but i can't get it to work.

So far I've tried to set the `SelectionAdapter` to the label but click-events aren't fired.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Labels are not selectable Controls SelectionAdapter won't work for it. Try adding a MouseListener.

Comment: Oh, i'm sorry, i tried adding a MouseAdapter as well, doesn't work either.

Comment: I had a wrapper around the label which didn't handle the click-event correctly. Mea culpa. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 5):

For sake of completeness, I'll just add this code sample:

```
label.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
   @Override
   public void mouseUp(MouseEvent event) {
      super.mouseUp(event);

      if (event.getSource() instanceof Label) {
         Label label = (Label)event.getSource();

         System.out.println("Label was clicked: " + label.getText());
      }
   }
});
```